# Работа с OnTriggerStay

Tags: c#, unity3d

В общем, не корректно работает триггер (возможно я чего-то не знаю), при использовании такого кода :

```
 void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
   
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(lootButton))
        {
            Debug.Log("buttonWasPushed");
        }
}
```

когда я нахожусь в коллайдере объекта и нажимаю на кнопку - лог дублируется (2 раза выводится одно и то же сообщение) , плюс ко всему, не все нажатия вообще воспринимаются, то есть я могу нажать 5 раз, и из пяти нажатий сообщение может вообще не выйти. (С кнопкой все ок, проверял на других)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мог бы сразу поставить вопрос таким образом.

```
public class Loot : MonoBehaviour {

    public void Taking () {
        DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
    }
}

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    private List<Loot> _closeLoot = new List<Loot>();

    private void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _closeLoot.Count > 0) {
            _closeLoot[0].Taking();
            _closeLoot.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
        if (other.GetComponent<Loot>() != null)
            _closeLoot.Add(other.GetComponent<Loot>());
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit (Collider other) {
        if (other.GetComponent<Loot>() != null)
            _closeLoot.Remove(other.GetComponent<Loot>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Или так. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно чего-то в первом-же обзаце документации:

[OnTriggerStay is called almost all the frames for every Collider other that is touching the trigger. The function is on the physics timer so it won't necessarily run every frame.](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html)

И хоть не в первом абзаце, но про то, как обнавляется `Input` тоже написано:

[Note also that the Input flags are not reset until Update. It is suggested you make all the Input calls in the Update Loop.](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html)

У них частоты разные и `OnTriggerStay` мягко говоря не место для `Input`.

Comment: Спасибо, буду исправлять

Answer (score 0):

Нашел альтернативу, кому интересно :

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(lootButton) && inTrigger == true)
        {
            wasPushed = true;
        }
    }
    

   
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        inTrigger = true   // Можно и OnTriggerEnter поставить, думаю сильно роли не играет.
        if (wasPushed == true)
        {
            Loot();
            wasPushed = false;

        }
    }
     void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
     {
        inTrigger = false;
     }
```

Получается, что в апдейте при нажатии на кнопку - меняется bool на true и в триггере (когда персонаж в нем) идет проверка, является ли bool true, если да - обрабатывается мой метод Loot(), и переменная bool становится false. Как-то так, я думаю решения еще есть, но это первое, что пришло в голову.

Comment: Получается можно нажать кнопку заранее и `wasPushed ` так и останется `true`, и подойдя к колайдеру, он сразу лутанёт без дальнейших импутов.

Comment: А теперь представь ситуацию, что 2 лута лежат рядом. Входишь в коллайдер первого, входишь в коллайдер второго, выходишь из коллайдера первого и хотя ты всё еще в коллайдере второго `inTrigger = false;`. И я всё ещё не понимаю, как ты лутаешь не имея ссылки на объект лута...?

Comment: Этот скрипт я применяю к условной "коробке", которая наполнена определенным лутом (или нет), Соответственно, скрипт будет добавлен к каждому подобному объекту ну и получается, что у каждого будет свой inTrigger.

Comment: Тестовый метод: `void Loot()
    {

        int rand = Random.Range(1, 5);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < inventory.database.transform.childCount; i++)
            {
                Item currentItem = inventory.database.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Item>();

                if (currentItem != null)
                {
                    if (currentItem.id == rand)
                    {
                        inventory.Message(currentItem);
                        inventory.AddToInventory(currentItem);
                    }

                }
            }
    }`

Comment: Сори, пару дней здесь, не шарю как код тут пихать в комменты.

Comment: А понял, тоже можно если 2 ящика никогда не будут рядом. Коммент через `(ё). В посте так-же происходит, если выделенный код не на отдельных строках, а по среди текста. Но переноса строки в комментах всё равно нет.

Comment: Я неделю где-то Unity уже занимаюсь, так что в дальнейшем буду исправлять. Пасиба, буду знать